# Old link structure to new url structure

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have our own CMS, and having some vacancies website's. Now the issue is, for SEO we've changed the page, where the vacacies are showed on, now google says 300 vacancies can't be found.

I'm asking for your help, since i dont want to changes 300 urls handy..

What i have here is the next url :

```
  website.html/vacatures/vacancieitem/289-docent-duits-1e-graad.html



  website.html/vacatures/vacancieitem/245-docent-wiskunde-1e-graad.html
```

Needs to go to the new url

```
  website.html/onderwijsvacatures/vacancieitem/289-docent-duits-1e-graad.html



  website.html/onderwijsvacatures/onderwijsvacatures/245-docent-wiskunde-1e-graad.html
```

and so go onn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following redirect in your htaccess :

```
Redirect 301 /vacatures/ /onderwijsvacatures/
```

Comment: Wow, i tried sometine like that before. Didnt knew it was that easy.. Thanks man..